# Setting the sizepolicy in qt

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qsizepolicy

I have a widget and a graphics view in the central widget of my application. The widget has four push buttons in it. I added the both in horizontal layout using the following code:

```
QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout;
layout->addWidget(ui->entityWidget);
layout->addWidget(ui->graphicsView);
ui->centralWidget->setLayout(layout);
```

I have set the size policy of the widget to be minimum and that of the graphics view to preferred. When I run the app, the widget is displayed appropriately in the top left corner but the graphics view's top left corner is in the middle of the central widget, which is not required. It should be right next to the widget.

How do I modify the size policy for correct placement of the graphics view in the main window?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not setting a parent widget to the Layout. That's likely your problem.

Try:

```
QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout(ui->centralWidget);
layout->addWidget(ui->entityWidget);
layout->addWidget(ui->graphicsView);
ui->centralWidget->setLayout(layout);
```

Also, if you post how your setting the SizePolicy that would help.

Comment: It remains the same. I have set the size policy in Qt Designer.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a stretch to the layout right after the graphicsView:

```
layout->addStretch();
```

Comment: After I do this, the widget in the left top is not visible. The graphics view overlaps it.

Comment: The reason can be the size polity, but anyway why don't you place all the widget as you need in Ui ? Why do you use both ui and code design?
Also the problem can be in the centralWidget. Is it placed in a layout?
If I understood your requirements correctly you need to do these things from the beggining:
1. Place a horizontal or vertical layout (depending of how you'd like buttons to be placed) on a form.
2. Drag buttons to the layout. [Screenshot](http://imgur.com/b3RBYnh)
3. Place graphics view to the right of the layout.
4. Click on an empty space and choose _Lay Out Horizontally_.

Comment: [Screenshot](http://imgur.com/1CKHDPN)  
5. Then you can setup margins in the properties of the form.  
let me know if you need something else

Comment: I was adding all the buttons to the widget and not to a layout, which I further added to the layout along with graphics view. Thanks so much for clarification. :)